# Django Serializer def validate validation error

Tags: django

In def validate i have unauthorized request error.
When i check these conditions separately, they are okay. But when i try to use them both, it raises ValidationError. Am i doing something wrong?

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    public_profile = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class UserFollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserFollow
        fields = ('id',"author","profile")

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if (attrs['author'].id == self.context['request'].user) and (attrs['profile'].public_profile == False):
            return attrs
        raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
```

Comment: `attrs['profile'].public_profile == False` looks strange. I would assume it is the opposite: that you access a public profile, so `and attrs['profile'].public_profile`.

Comment: It works if i only write `if attrs['profile'].public_profile == False:`. I am just having a problem if i use double IF condition check,thats what i am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing an integer with user model instance. Change to user.pk and might work. `attrs['author'].id == self.context['request'].user.pk`

Comment: It was actually string and it worked when it was left alone. Double IF conditions caused a problem, but your solution worked.